# Are there variants of "hold my beer" in different English dialects?

Tags: slang, dialects

The phrase "Hold my beer/drink (and watch this)" is a rather perjorative bit of slang - it implies that the speaker can perform the same act (or stunt) that he just observed someone else perform, implying that the act itself was trivially easy.

Since it seems to be a decidedly American saying, are there similar expressions within British, Australian, Canadian, African, or Indian English usage?

I'm just curious here.

Comment: I'd argue with your interpretation of the phrase; while it might *literally* mean "that's easy, I can do that", the context usually implies the opposite: "I'm too drunk to know that this is harder than it looks and is actually a stupid idea that is likely to hurt or kill me". It might be heard immediately before someone spectacularly fails to jump their 4-wheeler over their brand new pickup and instead destroys both.

Comment: That's why the perjorative.

Comment: It isn't pejorative. It's a challenge. Also, not sure it is AmE.

Answer (score 3):

I think

> hold my beer

Is recognised in the UK, and has the advantage also implying some drunken courage to boot.

There's a couple of similar phases I can think of;

> I could do that with one arm tied behind my back!

Or add more limbs being tied, more actions to give greater effect, eg I could do that with just my eyebrows whilst hopping on one leg!

For something that is a bit more physical, or if both you and the subject get hurt, the

> tis but a flesh wound

For reference to Monty Pythons Holy Grail. Not quite the same but surprisingly often useful!

Comment: The "it's a flesh wound" bit implies some kind of failure in the attempt, though it also says the speaker's willing to brush it off and try again.

"Your bike looks scratched up, mate."  "Yeah, dropped it sideways up the road. My pride's in hospital, but the rest of me's OK."

Comment: [There are a couple of phrases....//at least on this site.]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly "hold my coat", I can't find an idiom definition but here's a meme.

[image: obama]

Comment: This is more like acceptance of a challenge, but similar! Thanks.

Comment: That's more like "hold my rings." Hold my beer is something someone says before they strap themselves to the bottom of a pickup truck with bungie cord in order to diagnose noise coming from the rear differential. Or so I am told.

Answer (score 0):

Hold my coat...Manchester U.K.

Hold my beer sounds American and that you are in a social setting but still wanting to cause violence which is rather deplorable.

Answer (score 0):

Found this expression in a movie, maybe it has a similar meaning. Some can say "hold my (object)" right before getting into a fight or any kind of argument.

[image: White Chicks]

Answer (score -1):

Hold my coat/ beer / pint in 1950s England was all about bravado and aggression, it meant "I'm about to start a fight. I expect victory... Nothing to do with any stupid act per se.

It's far, far older only I've found a 'coat' variation from 2009 - 'pint/beer' is the usual, thus: "Hold my coat" I intend to royally kick the Bejesus out of somebody...:

'Kinell: someone hold my coat. If I have to see Hazel Bleugh's ratty little face trying to pathetically regain the moral highground, I will deck her, I really will... ['kinell: someone hold my coat](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/in_the_news/754942-39-Kinell-someone-hold-my-coat-If-I-have-to)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source to support your answer.